# correlation of a fit from colPivHouseholderQr().solve

Tags: c++, linear-regression, linear-algebra, eigen

I have some C++ code that is getting a bunch of X,Y values and doing
a linear fit

```
Eigen::Matrix<float, Eigen::Dynamic, 2> DX;
Eigen::Matrix<float, Eigen::Dynamic, 1> DY;
```

For loop over the data values (edited a bit because my data source
is a bit more complicated than simple arrays):

```
{
    DX(i,0) = x[i];
    DX(i,1) = 1;
    DY(i,0) = y[i];
}
```

then

```
Eigen::Vector2f Dsolution = DX.colPivHouseholderQr().solve(DY);

// linear solution  is in Dsolution[0] and Dsolution[1]
```

I need the correlation coefficient from that calculation.
How do I obtain it?

Most Eigen stuff is about two floors above my head, so you may need to spell it out in an elementary way.

The fundamental issue is that I'm running this routine on multiple data sets
and I need some indication of the quality of data as regards to internal noise and variance.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you give a bit more context ? What are DX and DY in your case ?

Comment: Edited to show the data types and general contents of DX and DY

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you are looking to compute the [R²](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_determination) coefficient of your least-square fitting.

### Linear least squares

First, let's recap what you're doing. In your `Dsolution` vector are two coefficients (lets call them `a` and `b`, which are your estimated parameters for an affine model between your `x`s and your `y` s). This means that for each `x[i]` your model's estimate for the corresponding `y[i]` is `estimated_y[i] = a * x[i] + b`.

`a` and `b` are computed by minimizing the sum of the squares of the difference between the observed `y[i]` and their estimated value `a*x[i] + b`, also called the **residuals**. It turns out that you can simply do that by solving a linear problem, which is why you use Eigen's `solve()` to find them.

### Computing R²

Now we want to compute R², which is an indicator of how "good" your fit is.

If we follow the definition from Wikipedia linked above, to compute R² you need to :

1. Compute the average of the observed values `y_avg`
2. Compute the **total sum of squares** i.e. the sum of the square differences between the observed values and their average  (this is like the variance but you don't divide by the number of samples)
3. Compute the **total sum of squared residuals** by summing the square of differences between the predicted and observed value of each `y`

Then R² is  `1 - (sum_residuals_squares / sum_squares)`

### Eigen code

Let's see how we can do this with Eigen :

```
float r_squared(const MatrixX2f& DX, const VectorXf& DY, const Vector2f& model)
{
    // Compute average
    const float y_avg = DY.mean();

    // Compute total sum of squares
    const int N = DX.rows();
    const float sum_squares = (DY - (y_avg * VectorXf::Ones(N))).squaredNorm();

    // Compute predicted values
    const VectorXf estimated_DY = DX * model;

    // Compute sum of residual squared
    const float sum_residuals_square = (DY - estimated_DY).squaredNorm();

    return 1 - (sum_residuals_square / sum_squares);

}
```

The trick used in both sum of squares's expression is to use the *squared norm* function, because the squared norm of a vector is the sum of squares of its components. We do it twice because we have two sum of squares to compute.

In the first case, we created a vector of size `N` full of ones that we multiply by `y_avg`, to get a vector whose elements are all `y_avg`. Then each element of DY minus that vector will be `y[i] - y_avg`, and we compute the square norm to get the total sum of squares.

In the second case, we first compute the predicted `y`'s by using your linear model, and then compute the difference with the observed values, using the squared norm to compute the sum of squared differences.

Comment: That is a beautiful answer!  Thanks!